# Adobe Creative SDK iOS Swift 'AdobeImageEditorPremiumAddOn' is unavailable error

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, adobe

I just started using Adobe Creative Cloud SDK and i'm getting an error as mentioned below.

> unknown:0: error: 'AdobeImageEditorPremiumAddOn' is unavailable
>   __ObjC.AdobeImageEditorPremiumAddOn:1:38: note: 'AdobeImageEditorPremiumAddOn' has been explicitly marked unavailable
>   here @availability(*, unavailable) struct AdobeImageEditorPremiumAddOn
>   : RawOptionSetType

This error is generating once i insert the below code

```
var imageView = AdobeUXImageEditorViewController(image: UIImage(named:"image.png"))

imageView.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(imageView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Even after adding app the frameworks exactly the way they have mentioned

Answer (score 1):

The only solution i found as a workaround is to create a Bridging Header and call it from Swift as shown below

This is Objective C

```
[[AdobeUXImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"img.jpg"]];

[editorController setDelegate:self];

[self presentViewController:editorController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and call the above code from swift as show below

```
 var view = objcViewController()
 self.navigationController!.presentViewController(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

if there is any better way to get it done please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue.  you need to do the following:

1) Create an Objective C method that takes a UIImage and initializes an AdobeUXImageEditorViewController

aviary.m

```
#import "aviary.h"

@implementation AviaryWrapper

+ (AdobeUXImageEditorViewController *)displayEditorForImage:(UIImage *) imageToEdit
{

    NSString* const CreativeSDKClientId = @""; //TODO use correct value
    NSString* const CreativeSDKClientSecret = @"";

    [[AdobeUXAuthManager sharedManager] setAuthenticationParametersWithClientID:CreativeSDKClientId withClientSecret:CreativeSDKClientSecret];

    AdobeUXImageEditorViewController *editorController = [[AdobeUXImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithImage: imageToEdit];

    return editorController;

}
@end
```

2) create aviary.h

```
#ifndef HelloWorld_aviary_h
#define HelloWorld_aviary_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AdobeCreativeSDKFoundation/AdobeCreativeSDKFoundation.h>
#import <AdobeCreativeSDKImage/AdobeCreativeSDKImage.h>



@interface AviaryWrapper : NSObject

+ (AdobeUXImageEditorViewController *)displayEditorForImage:(UIImage *) imageToEdit;

@end

#endif
```

3) Make sure to add aviary.h to your bridging header

in bridging header file

```
#import "aviary.h"
```

4) then simply call the AviaryWrapper class passing on your image

```
 var imageEditor = AviaryWrapper.displayEditorForImage(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage)
 presentViewController(imageEditor, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

(or in your case replace info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] with the actual image you want rendered.